# how to store attributes of multiple quantity using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, database-design, plsql

I need to implement an algorithm for a below-shared table in PL SQL.
for each ID in a table will have specified items(quantity) and corresponding volume and weight. every row ID will have any no. of items (i.e. 3->2,4->4 etc). in this scenario 3 row id will have 2 items and all 2 items will have volume and weight. now first of all need to find data structure in PLSQL to store the id and corresponding items, then again I need to store the volume and weight of each item and finally, I will add the volume and weight of each item to determine if it is fitting into my pack. so real challenge is here to store the volume and weight properties of each item based on ID.
As per

[image: order table]

below diagram is to specify the relationship between ID and item
[image]

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: My project is using PLSQL to interact with Oracle.

Comment: Please [post text not images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). It's not really clear what you're trying to do or how those two tables are related (or why both are needed), or where the 'pack' fits in. Is `item` an item ID or a quantity?

Answer (score 1):

you need a detail table and a header table, store the details of each individual item in the 'details' table have each item store a foreign key to its parent in the 'header' table, populate the header table with the compiled data from all the items.

Comment: I have one table in which I have the above-mentioned columns like ID, item, item volume and item weight. I need to iterate through each item and add the volume and weight of each item to determine if it is fitting into my pack.

Comment: @David: That seems to be good idea but How to loop through ID's from the header table and add the volume and weight in order to store them to detail table.

Comment: you could start your header record in 0 and have a stored procedure take care of that logic on every insert to the details table